# What is the effect of "chattr +a" on a directory

Tags: linux, directory, xattr

The `a` Linux file attribute is often documented as applicable to files.

chattr(1) manpage:

> A file with the 'a' attribute set can only be open in append mode  for  writing.

[ext4 wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout):

> 0x20  File can only be appended ([EXT4_APPEND_FL](http://osxr.org:8080/linux/source/fs/ext4/ext4.h#0369)).

My questions are:

- Is `chattr +a` restricted to files only?
- Is it recursive on new subdirectories and files?

Answer (score 12):

The *append only* flag (`chattr +a`) prevent from removing the directory, **a well as** files and directories created directly inside that directory:

Create test directory and files:

```
# mkdir     /tmp/foo
# chattr +a /tmp/foo
```

That directory can't be deleted:

```
# rmdir     /tmp/foo
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/tmp/foo’: Operation not permitted
```

Now create files and directory inside it:

```
# touch     /tmp/foo/bar
# mkdir     /tmp/foo/baz
```

Let's inspect that:

```
# lsattr -d /tmp/foo /tmp/foo/ba*
-----a-------e-- /tmp/foo
-------------e-- /tmp/foo/bar
-------------e-- /tmp/foo/baz
```

Try to erase stuffs:

```
# rm     /tmp/foo/bar
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/foo/bar’: Operation not permitted
# rmdir  /tmp/foo/baz
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/tmp/foo/baz’: Operation not permitted
rm -Rf /tmp/foo
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/foo/bar’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/foo/baz’: Operation not permitted
```

Finally, sub-sub-directory and files in sub-directories **are not protected**:

```
# mkdir            /tmp/foo/baz/bat
# touch            /tmp/foo/baz/baff
# rm --verbose -Rf /tmp/foo/baz
removed directory: ‘/tmp/foo/baz/bat’
removed ‘/tmp/foo/baz/baff’
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/foo/baz’: Operation not permitted
```

Again, note that only `/tmp/foo` had the append flag:

```
# lsattr -d  /tmp/foo /tmp/foo/baz
-----a-------e-- /tmp/foo
-------------e-- /tmp/foo/baz
```