# How to create Samba share accessible writable, readable but undeletable

Tags: linux, permissions, windows, shared-folders, samba4

I need to create Samaba share that contains directories and files undeletable for everybody but everybody must have permissions rwx. Is there is some bypass way tom make it? 
P.S.
On the server(Linux) side it can have any permissions.But can't be deleted from Windows(may be in this way)

Answer (score 0):

Write permission means delete permission as well, here's how:

If user has to have write permission, he can also "delete" file by writing single byte into the file and thus to delete all other content of that file.
There is no way that Samba detects OS, and based on that gives certain permissions.

Comment: I think that I can do that, but... I have to write high level application which will be determine delete option if user has specifically permissions.
But I was hope that samba has this layer permission...
Ofcourse on the OS level it's impossible

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `chattr +a <directory>` command to make the directory *append-only* at the filesystem level. Samba should not be able to side-step that. See this question:

[What is the effect of "chattr +a" on a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269020/what-is-the-effect-of-chattr-a-on-a-directory)

Comment: It's impossible, as I see. But I have solution for my case. Is to add mkdir to crontab