# Append only attribute for directories

Tags: xattr

I want to create a directory which is `undeletable`, and that you can only add files, not delete any file therein.

I was reading the `man chattr` page and I came across attribute `a`

> A file with the 'a' attribute set can only be opened in append mode for writing. Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

But it just mentions files. Can I apply it to a directory? Something like

```
sudo chattr +a +u /path/to/dir
```

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it yourself on a test directory?

Comment: @NasirRiley nice, yes, I tested and it works :) thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the effect of "chattr +a" on a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269020/what-is-the-effect-of-chattr-a-on-a-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
sudo chattr +a +u /path/to/dir
```